# How do I extend a pulsed signal in Rec Room circuits?

Tags: rec-room

I'm looking to take a signal and extend it a short amount of time. For instance, say I have an object inside a triggerzone and I'm monitoring the output of the green pin on that triggerzone. When the object is removed, I want the signal from the green pin to persist for at least a second longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the exact requirements you need, pulse extending or debouncing can be achieved with just a few chips.

### Boolean Debouncing

If all you need is the ability to extend a boolean value [0, 1], then all you need is the following circuit.

[image: Boolean Pulse Extender Circuit]

Send the number of ticks you would like to extend the signal into the green pin of the timer chip. It's a good idea to configure the timer chip to be a "Looping" timer, just to have a little bit more robustness. The red output of the OR chip will have the extended signal.

[Play around with this circuit here.](https://rrcs.tk/circuit/bcbJnyXhS)

### Integer Debouncing

If you need to pass through the value of the signal rather than just extending a boolean signal, then a bit more logic is required. There isn't a cheap way to do technically correct Integer debouncing, but this circuit gets close and it only adds 2 chips beyond the boolean debouncing circuit.

[image: Approximate Integer Debouncing]

In this circuit, the red output of the ≠ chip carries the extended integer pulse. As with the boolean debouncing circuit, send the number of ticks you'd like to extend the signal by into the green pin of the timer chip.

[Play around with this circuit here.](https://rrcs.tk/circuit/C4P2Xj1ok)